# How can I prevent opening URL in the browser using `cmd+ret` in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, url

If I am on top of a URL and pressed `Ctrl+Enter` (`C-m`), it opens the link on my default browser. I just want to have default behavior of `C-m`, which is new-line. Is it possible to prevent this while keeping `C-<mouse click on the URL>` to open it browser enabled.

---

Definition for `C-m` key returns following:

> RET runs the command org-return (found in org-mode-map), which is an
> interactive native compiled Lisp function in ‘org.el’.
>
> It is bound to RET,   .
>
> (org-return &optional INDENT ARG INTERACTIVE)
>
> Goto next table row or insert a newline.
>
> Calls ‘org-table-next-row’ or ‘newline’, depending on context.
>
> When optional INDENT argument is non-nil, call ‘newline-and-indent’
> with ARG, otherwise call ‘newline’ with ARG and INTERACTIVE.
>
> When ‘org-return-follows-link’ is non-nil and point is on a timestamp
> or a link, call ‘org-open-at-point’.  However, it will not happen if
> point is in a table or on a "dead" object (e.g., within a comment).
> In these case, you need to use ‘org-open-at-point’ directly.

Comment: What is `cmd`? Are you on MacOS? Is `cmd+ret` really bound to the same function as `cmd+m`? What happens if `org-returns-follows-link` is set to `nil`? As you might be able to tell, I find your question confusing.

Comment: @NickD Sorry I meant `cmd` == `Ctrl` // `(setq org-returns-follows-link nil)` did not help still opens the URL in the browser.

Comment: Oops - misspelt the variable: should be `org-return-follows-link` - can you try that?

Comment: No problem I just tried but still facing with the same issue :-(